# Refreshing elements in partial with jQuery

Tags: jquery, refresh, partial

In some point of my website, it receives "grades" ("notas" in portuguese) from users cellphone. So when a grade is received a have to update couple elements in this point of the site. I'm trying to use jQuery to make this refresh but it's not working. Here's what I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() { refresh() }, 3000);
  });

  function refresh() {    
    $.get("notas", function(data) {
      var chart = $(data).find('img').attr('src');
      var conclusion = $(data).find("#conclusion").html();

      $("img").attr('src', char);
      $("#conclusion").html(conclusion);      
    });    
  }
</script>
```

So, when a grade is added, that ajax get returns a html all set, so I'm pulling from that html couple fields and trying to replace on my current page. But nothing happens on the browser, there's no update.

When I visualize the souce code with "ctrl + U", (after new graded added) looks like fine but its not rendered like that. I guess I'm not letting the browser know that some changes happened on server.

Sorry for the big post, any thoughts what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding some debugging things, like console.log(chart), within your refresh function, to ensure that you are really getting the data you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't look at the source of your HTML document to see the dynamic changes you are making with jQuery. You need a DOM inspection tool like FireBug or Chrome Dev. Tools.

Some things I noticed:

1. Is "notas" the correct URL for your server-side script?
2. It appears as though your server response has an element with the ID of "conclusion" and you have the same ID already on the page. That's not good, each Id should be unique.
3. You have this line: `$("img").attr('src', char);` which doesn't seem to do anything to the DOM, the image you are creating is not being added to the page anywhere...

Comment: Thats correct about the DOM inspection, html source do not show what's happening on the browser. I just discovered the browser Web Console and could find that line you pointed out: $("img").attr('src', char); was breaking my script, because the correct var name its "chart" not "char". So, now it's working fine! thanks a lot! And now I love the browser web console :D

Comment: @brunosm You can do lots of useful things with developer tools like watch requests being sent, check-out the waterfall of assets being downloaded as your page is loaded, see in real-time what cookies are being made/altered/deleted, inspect the DOM, log data with `console.log()`, and there's more...